# Elasticsearch - find multiple exact values

Tags: elasticsearch

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/_finding_multiple_exact_values.html

```
{
  "terms" : {
    "price" : [20, 30]
  }
}
```

What is the max number of values we can put in this search?

"price" : [20, 30, 40, 50, 10, 11, 12 .... to the max number of search values]

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

searain,

The max number of terms is 1024, you can still change it for a higher number
using (in case if you are using it into a bool operator):

```
indices.query.bool.max_clause_count
```

into the .yml config file.